# Is there a better way to count the messages in an Message Queue (MSMQ)?

Tags: c#, performance, msmq

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(".\Private$\myqueue");
MessageEnumerator messageEnumerator = queue.GetMessageEnumerator2();
int i = 0;
while (messageEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    i++;
}
return i;
```

But for obvious reasons, it just feels wrong - I shouldn't have to iterate through every message just to get a count, should I?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# the answer appears to be no - what you are doing is one of the only ways to do this and all the others are similar.

There are ways to do this using WMI or COM - have a look at the [MSMQManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711378(VS.85).aspx) com component. This has a MessageCount property.

---

I found the following post that may give you some other ideas for slightly better pure C # implementations:

[Counting Messages in an MSMQ MessageQueue from C#](http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/counting-messages-in-an-msmq-messagequeue-from-c/)

While the above appears to be all true, I should note that I've never tried to do this with MSMQ - I've only ever done standard reading from the queues.

Answer (score 1):

```
            //here queue is msmq queue which you have to find count.        
            int index = 0;
            MSMQManagement msmq = new MSMQManagement() ;   
            object machine = queue.MachineName;
            object path = null;
            object formate=queue.FormatName;
            msmq.Init(ref machine, ref path,ref formate);
            long count = msmq.MessageCount();
```

This is faster than you selected one.
You get MSMQManagement class refferance inside "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" just browse in this address you will get it. for more details you can visit  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711378%28VS.85%29.aspx.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to get the count from messageQueue is

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(".\Private$\myqueue");
int iCount = queue.GetAllMessages().count();
```

Comment: The performance of this technique is terrible when the queue is over 10k messages.

Comment: Furthermore, it might throw OutOfMemoryException if there are too many messages in queue.